# Unable to use margin-bottom to increase spacing between headers

Tags: css

I have heard about collapsing margins but am not sure if this is what's happening. Here is a mini-version of the code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtDGQ/). I am trying to increase the spacing between "title" and "I am text" to 45 px by applying margin-bottom to "title". Can someone help me figure out the problem? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<header id="title">Title</header>
<h6>I am text.</h6>
```

CSS:

```
header #title {
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:45px;
font-family: "Book Antiqua";
}

h6 {
font-style: italic;
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: normal;
margin-top: 12pt;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You have no element with the id `title` _inside_ of a `header` element …

Comment: the header tag should have the h6 tag init

Comment: As @CBroe noted, use `header#title` instead, or simply `#title` since the id is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a black space between **header** and **#title** in your css code. Remove it.

`header #title {` should be `header#title {`

Check the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calinsargan/xtDGQ/1/

Comment: That's a really silly reason... I have been trying to figure out the problem for an hour already... T___T Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change `header #title {` to `#title {`.